# Is there a balancing Scheme REPL for *nix?

Tags: linux, unix, command-line, scheme

I would like a command-line (must be a command line!) read-eval-print-loop Scheme interpreter. But spefically, I'd like an interpreter than can at least highlight parentheses, and maybe even keep a history like GNU readline-enabled programs. All of this at REPL-level.

Does this exist? Is it even possible? Do I have to hack this into some open-source REPL? Am I just bad at computer? Should I even bother?

I've checked other questions for this but I haven't quite found what I'm looking for. I've tried Racket and mzscheme, but it doesn't seem to do what I want.
For now I'm using mit-scheme, but that balancing feature (much like whatever program they used in the SICP lectures) would be pretty much all I could ever want from it.

Comment: Pro-tip for using any REPL (not just Scheme REPLs) is a little utility called `rlwrap`. You should be able to install it on most *nix systems. Call it like `rlwrap scheme` and it will wrap input to the REPL with readline, giving you history, nicer editing, etc... Invaluable if the REPL is really basic like Clojure's. I don't think this is specifically answering your need, so I didn't make it an answer, but it might be useful in general. Also, I think you can start most Schemes as inferior-lisps in Emacs, which give you much more, but I won't go so far as to push that :)

Comment: @spacemanaki: Does rlwrap support vi editing mode? That's one thing I <3 about readline (and libedit).

Comment: Good question -- I don't know. A quick search turns up some likely results, but I wouldn't be a good person to test it out, I haven't used readline's vi-mode in a long time, so I couldn't tell you if it's comparable.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Both [Racket](http://www.racket-lang.org/) (with readline support loaded; see below) and [Chez Scheme](http://www.scheme.com/) will do this. :-) So will [Guile](http://www.gnu.org/software/guile/), but it will fold multi-line forms into a single line (unlike Racket/Chez).

---

To enable bracket matching for Racket, add this line to your `~/.racketrc`:

```
(#%require readline/rep)
```

and this line to your `~/.inputrc`:

```
set blink-matching-paren on
```

Comment: It's actually `set blink-matching-paren on`. No 's'. Thanks!

Comment: Chez will also indent for you at the REPL, and that's really nice.